# How to add a symbol after I'm typing on input field?

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I add a symbol after the text that I'm typing on input field. So when I type for instance a text after the text i would like to be a symbol but i don't want to be repeated. My actual code add the symbol every time i typed. I attached the code I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pd',
  templateUrl: './pd.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pd.component.sass']
})
export class PdComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  kup(event) {
    event.target.value = event.target.value+'e';
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" (keyup)="kup($event)">
```

Comment: So add it on blur?

Comment: When i type on input

Comment: problem with typing is it screws up the user's cursor when you update the value so it is more complicated than just updating the value.

Answer (score 2):

Don't add the `e` if it's already there.

```
  kup(event) {
    if (!/e$/.test(event.target.value)) {
      event.target.value = event.target.value+'e';
    }
  }
```

Note that this can't distinguish an `e` that they type from the one that's added by your method. I can't think of a good way to solve that.

Comment: It's the same result. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use focusout event instead keyup.

```
<input type="text" (focusout)="kup($event)">
```